# Graphics software

Tags: software

Do you have any suggestions about free mathematical graphics software? I need to do some drawings of polyhedrons and a drawing of intersection between polyhedron and a circle.

Comment: if you have access to Mathematica that should cover all your needs (it has an extensive collection of polyhedra); it is not free.

Comment: Do you need your software to do the computation, or you want to draw "yourself"?  In the latter case, you can use inkscape.

Comment: @user43326 It would be ideal, if I could only tell the software what objects I want to work

Comment: Regardless of whether you are better at programming or at drawing, I believe any software you can try has a learning curve attached to it. I think it is unrealistic to expect that at the very first use you will tell it what you want and it will do it. You will need to apply some time and effort. If you have some experience with graphics software, you might need as little as a couple of hours. If not, it might be a couple of days or more. Free software is usually more difficult to master.

Comment: There's an enormous amount of software available.  That said, I often just draw things with a paper and pencil, then take a photograph.  It works well-enough.

Answer (score 3):

[sagemath](https://www.sagemath.org/) is free, open source, and has an extensive [library](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plot3d/) of 3d graphics, including many polyhedra.